# PHP mail: Email field won't print

Tags: php, html, html-email

This is the first time I'm using PHP's mail function and have it working nicely except that I can't seem to get the user's email address to print to the submission form data that is emailed back to the form recipient.

Currently, when I get the form data, it looks like so (as you can see, the email field is empty):

[image]

Here's my form code:

```
<form id="contact" action="process.php" method="post" role="form">
<!---snip to save space and show relevant code--->
<label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control input-lg" tabindex="3">
```

My process.php code:

```
<?php

$recipient = "johndoe@aol.com";
$subject = "FORM SUBMISSION";

$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
$lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
$replyTo = $_POST['email'];
$sender = "From: $replyTo\r\n";
$message = $_POST['message'];
$whyContact = $_POST['whyContact'];

$sender = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$sender = "Content-type: text/html; charset=us-ascii\n";

$msgBody = "
<html>
<head>
<title>title here</title>
</head>

<style type='text/css'>

body{width:100% !important; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}
table td {border-collapse: collapse;}
table { border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; }

</style>

<body>

<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0' style='width:100%;border-bottom:1px solid #eee;font-size:12px;line-height:135%;font-family:'Lucida Grande','Lucida Sans Unicode', Tahoma, sans-serif'>
<tr style='background-color:#F5F5F5'>
<th style='vertical-align:top;color:#222;text-align:left;padding:7px 9px 7px 9px;border-top:1px solid #eee;'>Name:</th>
<td style='vertical-align:top;color:#333;width:60%;padding:7px 9px 7px 0;border-top:1px solid #eee;'>$firstName $lastName</td>
</tr>
<tr style='background-color:#FFFFFF'>
<th style='vertical-align:top;color:#222;text-align:left;padding:7px 9px 7px 9px;border-top:1px solid #eee;'>Email:</th>
<td style='vertical-align:top;color:#333;width:60%;padding:7px 9px 7px 0;border-top:1px solid #eee;'>$replyTo</td>
</tr>
<tr style='background-color:#F5F5F5'>
<th style='vertical-align:top;color:#222;text-align:left;padding:7px 9px 7px 9px;border-top:1px solid #eee;'>What are you contacting us about?</th>
<td style='vertical-align:top;color:#333;width:60%;padding:7px 9px 7px 0;border-top:1px solid #eee;'>$whyContact</td>
</tr>
<tr style='background-color:#FFFFFF'>
<th style='vertical-align:top;color:#222;text-align:left;padding:7px 9px 7px 9px;border-top:1px solid #eee;'>Message:</th>
<td style='vertical-align:top;color:#333;width:60%;padding:7px 9px 7px 0;border-top:1px solid #eee;'>$message</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
";

mail($recipient, $subject, $msgBody, $sender);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overriding `$sender` with each assignment which means your `From` and `MIME-Version` headers are being dropped. Try Something like:

```
$sender  = "From: $replyTo\r\n";
$sender .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$sender .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=us-ascii\n";
```

Comment: Thanks, Emily. Unfortunately, it did not make a difference:(

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I forgot to add the "." to the two $sender variables in my example. Thanks!